# sql query to filter dates of this week

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to `sql` queries, can anyone help me for writing query for the following condition
I have a column named "dob" in table "members". **Note: dob datatype is text.**
And the values like :

```
dob
===
7-November-1980
9-November-1981
10-November-1982
5-May-1990
```

Now to get birthdays of this week (i.e) from 7-11-2012 to 13-11-2012 , I want to get the result as first 3 records. For that I wrote query like this

```
select * from members where dob in('7-November','8-November','9-November','10-November','11-November','12-November','13-November')
```

But it never returns any results. Anyone please help me that how can I get it. Big thanks to you.

Comment: why r u not writing year also with the values in `IN` operator

Comment: The `IN` statement is going to look for exact matches. Why are the dates formatted as text? Can you change the format? If so, I think that this would make this easier to solve.

Comment: Is there no other go other than changing the format of column, because its gonna a big change in my project and it may cause other module to not work

Comment: Sure, you could make it work. But I think that we need more information in order to solve it properly. How is the search criteria / week selected?

Comment: Search criteria is from today date to next one week. We have to compare only date and month only,

Comment: Hi Joe, i am waiting for your answer. Help needed please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dates are not stored in one of [SQLite's supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so this query becomes rather complex:

```
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE dob LIKE '7-November%' OR
      dob LIKE '8-November%' OR
      dob LIKE '9-November%' OR
      dob LIKE '10-November%' OR
      dob LIKE '11-November%' OR
      dob LIKE '12-November%' OR
      dob LIKE '13-November%'
```

If you stored the dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format with fixed field widths, you could use a simpler query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM members
WHERE SUBSTR(dob, 6, 5) BETWEEN '11-07' AND '11-13'
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing a exact text match, i.e. 7-November-1980 is not equal to 7-November, thats why your query is not returning any results. Try converting your text to datetime using mysql date function, extract date-month from it and then use a range query to get your results.
check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html